# JavaScript Zooming Chart function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, zooming, linechart

I wrote this JavaScript code to trace Line chart and after finishing I need to modify my code to allow zooming by mouse selection and panning canvas.

```
function zoom(){
    startindex = document.getElementById("startpoint").selectedIndex;
    endindex= document.getElementById("endpoint").selectedIndex;
    var newlabels=oldlabels.slice(startindex, endindex);
    var newdata=oldDatas.slice(startindex,endindex);
    data.labels= newlabels;
    data.datasets.data=newdata;
    myChart = new Chart(context).Line(data);
 }
```

[the link to my chart](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1eahgd3yx6tr20x/MyLineChart.js)

Answer (score 0):

**Learn the context.translate and context.scale methods.**

Knowing these will let you pan & zoom.

The basics of zoom are:

- translate to the point you want to zoom into
- scale the canvas to the desired zoom level
- erase the canvas
- redraw the chart at -chartWidth/2 and -chartHeight/2.

Pan is even easier:

- translate by the x-distance you want to pan
- erase the canvas
- redraw the chart at 0,0